# CSS Styling for 'a' (anchor tag) is not working

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have some hyperlink but class and id of it are already used by other scripts. So how can I add some css to them ? I tried 2 things.

```
<div class='some_css'>
<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' class='used' id='used1'>link1</a>
<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' class='used' id='used2'>link2</a>
</div>

///css file
.some_css:a
{
color:#456e9c;
}
```

Another try

```
<span class='some_css'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' class='used' id='used1'>link1</a></span>
<span class='some_css'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' class='used' id='used2'>link2</a></span>

///css file   
.some_css:a
{
color:#456e9c;
}
```

Both are wrong.....
I know I do something wrong, please help

Comment: Why can't you use the classes or ids again?  Do you mean some other css is already affecting the class and id and you are unable to override it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a space, not a colon (`:`). Colons are meant for stuff like pseudo-classes/elements, and properties.

```
.some_css a
{
color:#456e9c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

replace the colon (':') by a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
.some_css a {

}
```

(in other words, lose the ':')

Answer (score 1):

Target a contained inside .some_css

```
.some_css a {
  color:#456e9c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' class='used other_class' id='used1'>link1</a>
```

So you can define more than one class to an element with using space as a seperator...